# Hapi js throwing Error: Already closed

Tags: node.js, exception, hapi.js

I am using Hapi.js as a framework for our API development, and i am getting following error in very rare scenario.

```
2015-02-08T12:32:38.073Z - verbose: err.stack >  Error: Already closed
    at Object.exports.create (/var/www/ragchewAppServerSrc/ragchew_prod/ragchews/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/boom/lib/index.js:21:17)
    at Object.exports.internal (/var/www/ragchewAppServerSrc/ragchew_prod/ragchews/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/boom/lib/index.js:252:92)
    at /var/www/ragchewAppServerSrc/ragchew_prod/ragchews/node_modules/hapi/lib/request.js:297:34
    at iterate (/var/www/ragchewAppServerSrc/ragchew_prod/ragchews/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/items/lib/index.js:35:13)
    at done (/var/www/ragchewAppServerSrc/ragchew_prod/ragchews/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/items/lib/index.js:27:25)
    at validate (/var/www/ragchewAppServerSrc/ragchew_prod/ragchews/node_modules/hapi/lib/auth.js:283:20)
    at finish (/var/www/ragchewAppServerSrc/ragchew_prod/ragchews/node_modules/hapi/lib/protect.js:45:21)
    at wrapped (/var/www/ragchewAppServerSrc/ragchew_prod/ragchews/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:798:20)
    at root (/var/www/ragchewAppServerSrc/ragchew_prod/ragchews/node_modules/hapi/lib/auth.js:198:50)
    at /var/www/ragchewAppServerSrc/ragchew_prod/ragchews/src/middlewares/auth/ragchew_auth_strategy.js:75:28
2015-02-08T12:32:38.073Z - verbose: err >  {"isBoom":true,"output":{"statusCode":500,"payload":{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server
```

Neither am able to reproduce this in our testing environment, nor i understand the root cause of this error.

It would be great help if some-one highlight why/when this error is generated by framework.

In our code this error occur when we try to send the reply back from 'Authentication plugin'. We are using basic authentication scheme.

Sample snippet where issue occurs is:

```
exports.register = function (plugin, options, next) {
    plugin.auth.scheme('basic', function (server, options) {
        var settings = options;
        // some code here
        var scheme = {
            authenticate: function (request, reply) {
                // some code here
                // assign access token value to token here.

                settings.validateFunc.call(request, token, function (err, isValid, credentials) {
                    // handle error here.
                    return reply(null, { credentials: credentials });   // error occurs on this line
                });
            }
        };
        return scheme;
    });

    next();
};
```

Comment: This part of the code looks good. I think the problem will be somewhere else. Can you add the "some code here" parts too?

Comment: Actually, there is lot of code, so i would rather be more interested in knowing when this error is thrown so that i myself solve the issue.

Comment: which hapi version do you use ?

Comment: I am using 7.0.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `return reply.continue({credentials: credentials});` on success instead of what you have now?

See this line in hapi-auth-basic for reference:

https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-basic/blob/master/lib/index.js#L83